# Drawing a pair of pants using python

Tags: geometry, surfaces, parametric

I am trying to draw a helicoidale trajectory on a pair of pants and to do this I need a parametric equation of the surface. Then I will compose $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ with the parametrized equation.

Thus, I am trying to find the equation of a pair of pants.
I found this:

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-mathematical-expression-which-when-plotted-looks-like-a-pair-of-pants

The idea is well thought but I don't have really good results while drawing it...

Q: Do someone have any idea of the equation of a pair of pants ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why the solution in the Quora article (the surface $(1-z)((x-1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3)((x+1)^2 + y^2 - 1/3) + z (x^2 + y^2 - 1/3) = 0$) doesn't give "good results"?  Does the equation need to be in a different form?  If so, what kind of form?

Comment: I meant that when I plot it with my own implicit function program (that plot) I do not have the good result ! Do you know any surface that would look like a tube and that 'split' in two 'tubes' ? ANd for the form, I would prefere a parametric form but I can deal with others too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the equation from Quora as plotted using Maple, with the following commands:

```
eq:= (1-z)*((x-1)^2+y^2-1/3)*((x+1)^2+y^2-1/3) + z*(x^2+y^2-1/3):
plots:-implicitplot3d(eq, x=-1.7..1.7, y=-0.7..0.7, z=0..1, grid=[100,60,30],
  scaling=constrained, axes=none, style=patchnogrid, lightmodel=light2);
```

[image]

What don't you like about it?

EDIT: If you want a parametric curve $x = X(t), y = Y(t), z = Z(t)$ on a surface defined by the implicit equation $F(x,y,z) = 0$, you could use a system of differential equations $\dot{x} = f_1(x,y,z),\; \dot{y} = f_2(x,y,z),\; \dot{z} = f_3(x,y,z)$.  What you need in order to have the curve stay on the surface is
$$ \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} \dot{x} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} \dot{y} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z} \dot{z} = 0$$
You will probably want to use numerical methods to solve the system of differential equations.

Here, for example, is a curve winding up one leg of the pants and onto the torso.

[image]

EDIT: The differential equation system I used was

$$ \eqalign{\dot{x} &= \partial F/\partial y - \dfrac{ (\partial F/\partial x) (\partial F/\partial z)}{10 ((\partial F/\partial x)^2 + (\partial F/\partial y)^2)}\cr
   \dot{y} &= - \partial F/\partial x - \dfrac{(\partial F/\partial y) (\partial F/\partial z)}{10 ((\partial F/\partial x)^2 + (\partial F/\partial y)^2)}\cr
\dot{z} &= 1/10\cr} $$
where $$ F = \left( 1-z \right)  \left(  \left( x-1 \right) ^{2}+{y}^{2}-1/3
 \right)  \left(  \left( x+1 \right) ^{2}+{y}^{2}-1/3 \right) +z
 \left( {x}^{2}+{y}^{2}-1/3 \right) $$

Comment: Ok I guess I was wrong on the efficiency of my program.... What I do not achieve is the composition of that surface and an helix. To clarify, I want to draw an helix shaped like a surface (for instance a cylinder, a torus, a square..). The pair of pants shaped surface is still giving me troubles. I do not understand how can I 'compose' my helix with that surface... Thank you for your answer, do not hesitate to ask me more questions about it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "composing" a helix with the surface.  If you want to wrap a helix around it, the fact that the surface has three holes  will be a problem.

Comment: when you compose (cos(t), sin(t)) with the parametric equation of a torus you obtain a helix curve on a torus like describe in the first answer of that post:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1044942/example-of-differentiable-curve-and-tangent-vector-on-the-torus

Comment: "Any curve γ(t)=(u(t),v(t)) whatsoever in R2, when composed with R, gives a curve on the torus. "

Comment: No, when you compose $(\cos(t), \sin(t))$ with the parametric equations of a torus you obtain a closed loop on the torus.

Comment: Yes, this is (approximatly) what I want to do ! The problem is that I have no idea on how to draw a closed loop on a surface that is defined only with an implicit equation..... Technically, I am supposed to draw helix(s) on a surface.... I thought it was with the composition of a circle (from R2) and a surface.

Comment: Thank you, this is the information I wanted !

Comment: I am really trying my best to understand how to find the f1(x,y,z), f2(x,y,z), f3(x,y,z) so if you still have time to explain (maybe just the main steps to find them ?) please. The Point I do not understand is why that system gives a helix on the surface ? thank you for your attention

Comment: $\dot{x} = \partial F/\partial x$, $\dot{y} = -\partial F/\partial y$, $\dot{z} = 0$ would keep $z$ constant, so a curve at constant height.  I made $\dot{z} = 1/10$ so $z$ would be slowly increasing, and added terms to $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{y}$ that would keep $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x} \dot{x} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} \dot{y} + \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial z} \dot{z} = 0$.

Comment: Ok it is kinda 'feeling' I understand, my new problem is that the equation system I write is not linear ( for example the first equation, x' is in function of the derivatives of y and z) is it normal ? How did you managed to express x' in term of x, y and z (and thus eliminate the y' and z') ? Thank you for your attention I really appreciate !